# PhpStorm 2018.1 cant open Xdebug profiler snapshot

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PHP 5.6 on Windows (XAMPP) with Xdebug 2.5.5. But when I open snapshot with PhpStorm I've got an error

> Incorrect profiler snapshot format: incorrect file name(ffl=(1))

Comment: **1)** Try latest IDE version (2018.3) **2)** Are you sure about Xdebug version? This one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39256 was fixed fro 2018.1.6. **3)**  Other forum topics: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000413450-PhpStorm-Profiling-with-XDebug-Incorrect-profiler-snapshot-format-Incorrect-name-format- and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000394750-Can-t-open-xdebug-snapshot-in-phpstorm

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks! Latest version works nice!